# How can I delete duplicate values from a hash of hash

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, hash

I need a unique hash , where the value of `"one"` should never repeat.

for example,

```
hash= {"1"=>{"one"=>1,"two"=>2},
   "2"=>{"one"=>1,"two"=>3},
   "3"=>{"one"=>2,"two"=>3},
   "4"=>{"one"=>1,"two"=>2}}
```

then the result should be,

```
hash= {"1"=>{"one"=>1,"two"=>2},
    "3"=>{"one"=>2,"two"=>3}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ones_values = {}
hash.delete_if do |key, value|
  ones_values[value["one"]] ? true : (ones_values[value["one"]] = true) && false
end
```

Answer (score 5):

(readable) one-liner:

```
hash.to_a.uniq {|(_,v)| v['one']}.to_h
# {"1"=>{"one"=>1, "two"=>2}, "3"=>{"one"=>2, "two"=>3}}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
hash.inject({}) do |memo, (k, v)| 
  memo[k] = v unless memo.values.any? do |mv| 
                       mv['one'] == v['one']
                     end
  memo
end

#⇒ {
#    "1" => {
#      "one" => 1,
#      "two" => 2
#    },
#    "3" => {
#      "one" => 2,
#      "two" => 3
#    }
#  }
```

Comment: for the above set of values the answer is ok .But , when i implemented it in rails for some hash i got the following  message: undefined method `values' for nil:NilClass

Comment: The code above can’t produce this error message. You introduce some error while implementing it in rails. It looks like you’ve forgotten to return memo from each loop iteration.